# nginx gzip Vary header together with existing Vary headers

Tags: nginx, gzip

I'm trying to active gzip compression and I have set the option gzip_vary on; to include the Vary: Accept-Encoding header.

The problem is, my application is already seting a Vary: header.
So the response is now having two Vary: headers, one from my application and one from nginx.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 17 Dec 2016 13:28:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Sat, 17 Dec 2016 13:28:38 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

But I guess instead it should be rather like this:

```
Vary: Accept-Encoding, User Agent
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think the best thing to do is to file a bug report on nginx.

Comment: I have raised https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1204

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) states duplicate headers are acceptable and should be treated the same as a single header with a comma-separated list of values:

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when a message is forwarded.

So, you don't need to do anything to get the proper behavior.

Comment: Thanks; I think you're right. I have checked and our Varnish caches seem happy enough with multiple "Vary" headers, so this isn't actually a problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use gzip in that way.

```
gzip on;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js image/gif image/jpeg application/atom+xml application/rss+xml text/x-component image/png image/tiff image/vnd.wap.wbmp image/x-icon image/x-jng image/x-ms-bmp image/svg+xml image/webp application/font-woff application/msword application/pdf;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
```

Check this link for more [Compress traffic between uwsgi-nginx and nginx load balancer](https://serverfault.com/questions/830090/compress-traffic-between-uwsgi-nginx-and-nginx-load-balancer/830124#830124)

Comment: (I don't think this answers the question that is being asked here)