# Compress traffic between uwsgi-nginx and nginx load balancer

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, uwsgi

I have 7 nginx webservers running a python app and serving it to nginx via uwsgi and a socket file, infront of these 7 webservers there is an nginx load balancer, the trafic that gets out of the load balancer to the public is compressed correctly resuling to only ~20Mbps  of outgoing trafic , however the trafic that gets out of the webservers and to the load balancer for some reason doesnt get compressed resulting in the loadbalancer to have a total incoming trafic(from the servers subnet interface) of 400Mbps and each of the web servers to ahve about 70Mbps of outgoing traffic.

Should the gzip compression be enabled the same way it was enabled on the laod balancer(where it works) ? is it some diferent configuration here?

**Web servers nginx.conf:**

```
user xxx;
worker_rlimit_nofile 99999;
worker_processes  16;

events {
    worker_connections 65535;
}
http {
    proxy_cache_path  /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:8m max_size=3000m inactive=600m;
    proxy_temp_path /tmp;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 620;
        keepalive_requests 20000;
#   types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 200m;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    #ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    proxy_buffer_size   128k; 
    proxy_buffers   16 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
    uwsgi_buffer_size 128k;
    uwsgi_buffers 16 256k;
    uwsgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
#   uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME https;
#   uwsgi_param HTTPS on;

    #log info
    log_format  main  '[$time_local] - $remote_addr - $request_time - $remote_user - $upstream_addr - "$request" '
                     '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" $http_host $http_cookie';
    log_format  body  '[$time_local] - $remote_addr - $request_time - $remote_user - "$request" '
                     '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" $http_host $request_body $http_cookie';

    access_log off;
    #access_log /home/xxx/log/ng_access.log;
    error_log /home/xxx/log/ng_error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    open_file_cache          max=8000 inactive=60s;
    open_file_cache_valid    120s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors   off;
    #uwsgi_buffering  off;

    #the cdn server, listening on port 83
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/cdn.conf;

    #the xxx app, listening on port 81
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/xxx.conf;

    #the dealers app, listening on port 82
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/dealers.conf;

    #a fallback server listening on port 80, it acts as a local "load balancer" in case that we need to use this server without
    #a load balancer
    include /etc/nginx/conflb.d/http_upstreams.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conflb.d/xxx.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conflb.d/dealers.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conflb.d/es.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conflb.d/db.conf;

}
```

**Load balancer nginx.conf:**

```
user nginx;
worker_rlimit_nofile 99999;
worker_processes  15;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  65535;
}
http {

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/http_upstreams.conf;

        sendfile        on;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;
        proxy_buffers 4 64k;
        #proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        keepalive_timeout  620;
        gzip  on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
    client_max_body_size 200m;
    #log info
    log_format  main  '[$time_local] - $remote_addr - $request_time - $remote_user - $upstream_addr - "$request" '
                     '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" $http_host $http_cookie';
    log_format  body  '[$time_local] - $remote_addr - $request_time - $remote_user - "$request" '
                     '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" $http_host $request_body $http_cookie';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;


        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/db1.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/db2.conf;   
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/es.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/st.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/xxx.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/dealers.conf;

    #catch all server
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://www.xxx.gr$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey man use gzip compression like this

```
    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js image/gif image/jpeg application/atom+xml application/rss+xml text/x-component image/png image/tiff image/vnd.wap.wbmp image/x-icon image/x-jng image/x-ms-bmp image/svg+xml image/webp application/font-woff application/msword application/pdf;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
```

Comment: Unfornunately it doesnt work, the traffic continues to be +70 Mbps

Comment: I tried this but didn't worked